# Can you plot multiple precision-recall curves using PrecisionRecallDisplay?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am trying to plot Precision Recall curve using [PrecisionRecallDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.html) from scikit-learn.

I have model predicted values in `y_pred` and actual values in `y_true`. I can plot precision recall curve using the following syntax:

```py
metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(y_true, y_pred)
```

But I want to plot multiple curves (say by applying model on training or validation data) in the same plot.

So is it possible to achieve this using  `PrecisionRecallDisplay`? Or Is there some other standard way to achieve this using scikit-learn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since sklearn display routines are basically just matplotlib wrappers, the easiest way seems to be utilizing the `ax` argument, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(y_train, y_pred_train, ax=ax)
PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(y_test, y_pred, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked! thnx